# Split and merge back gulp-usemin streams

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I just started playing with gulp.js.

A package I find very useful is `usemin`, as it allows to concat files in the same order they are required in the html file.

As I use angular.js I wanted to know if there's a way of merging 2 groups of files into one without first writing them to filesystem. I'll give an example:

```
<!-- build:js -->
<script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:ng -->
<script src="js/dashboard.controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/data.service.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

I would like to be able to run `ng-annotate` only on the `ng` "target" and then `concat` all the `.js` files into one, of course referenced only by one `<script>` in the compiled html file and possibly without having an intermediate filesystem write.

The easiest way would probably be not to differentiate between the different `.js` (angular and non-angular) files and run `ng-annotate` on everything, but I am looking for a more efficient and flexible approach.

I'm even thinking of trying to hack the usemin plugin, but it looks a bit hard right now. Then does anybody think this is a silly question and I should take a different approach?

Comment: Gulp-usemin seems to be blacklisted in gulp [plugins site](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/blob/e77d480648f529b3741ba32b3d0baa49a1b23e7e/src/blackList.json#L32). It recommends using [gulp-useref](https://github.com/jonkemp/gulp-useref) instead.

Comment: You could try https://github.com/futurechan/gulp-asset-transform